# How to drawtext colon with localtime in ffmpeg -filter_complex?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext='fontfile=font.ttf : text=%{localtime\:%Y/%m/%d %H%M%S} : fontsize=24 : fontcolor=white : x=10: y=10'" out.mp4
```

works.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext='fontfile=font.ttf : text=%{localtime\:%Y/%m/%d %H\:%M\:%S} : fontsize=24 : fontcolor=white : x=10: y=10'" out.mp4
```

returns

> %{localtime} requires at most 1 arguments

error.

the only difference is `\:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
%{localtime\:%Y/%m/%d %H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}
```

It's ugly. See [FFmpeg: Quoting & Escaping](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping) for some info.

Comment: How to know the number of \ needed?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows with `.bat` file I have to escape it like:

```
%%{localtime\:%%Y/%%m/%%d %%H\\\:%%M\\\:%%S}
```