# FFMpeg - Print Date and Time during recording like surveillance

Tags: datetime, video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I need to record video from RaspberryPi, using this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 320x240 -framerate 15 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -an "/var/ayron/videotrap/videos/pctrace_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").h264"
```

In this way, I can report the date and time of start recording. But I need to show on video the Date and Time during registration. Which kind of filter must I use?

Thanks for your supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 320x240 -framerate 15 -i /dev/video0 -an -vf "drawtext=text='%{localtime\:%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S}'" "/var/ayron/videotrap/videos/pctrace_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").h264"
```

- You can't filter and [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video at the same time so `-vcodec copy` has been omitted.
- If you want to use colons (`:`) in the time then you'll have to do some ugly escaping as shown in [How to drawtext colon with localtime in ffmpeg -filter_complex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046375/)